# i am unable to ping two Vms each other on hyper v manager tool

Tags: server, virtual-machine

in my windows 10 system i have created two  virtual machine using Hyper-v Manager tool one is Redhat-Linux and second one is windows 10 for sql server, and i am trying to  ping from Redhat-Linux to sql server and sql server to Redhat_Linux each others  but it is not pinging  .
Can anyone give me  the solution for this issue .

Comment: Can you add more information? VM network information? How are the two VMs connected? Etc

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if both VM's connected to the same network? (eg. private, internal or public?)
can you ping the vm's from your host? Do they get ip addresses, and are they in the same range?